# Trouble returning JSON data with custom datatype using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having trouble using this code that essentially downloads JSON data and parses it, to return the returnInfo. When I print the info it is intact however when it is returned the struct defaults are returned. Not sure what I"m doing wrong any help would be highly appreciated!

Let me know if you need any additional information and I would be happy to provide it.

```
import Foundation

struct stockData {
   var name: String = ""
   var askPrice: String = ""
   var percentageChange: String = ""
}

class stockinfo {

    init () {

    }

    func getInfo (stock: String) -> stockData{

            let stockSymbol = stock // Sets stock symbol
            var returnInfo = stockData()

            // Configuration for request and starts the connection

        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + stockSymbol + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("JSON File Downloaded Successfully")

                do{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                    // Parses out the JSON Query into data to be assigned to a variable and returned

                    let query: NSDictionary = json["query"] as! NSDictionary
                    let results: NSDictionary = query["results"] as! NSDictionary
                    let quote: NSDictionary = results["quote"] as! NSDictionary
                    let companyName: String = quote["Name"] as! String
                    let askPrice: String = quote["Ask"] as! String
                    let percentageChange: String = quote["ChangeinPercent"] as! String

                    // Places JSON data into return struct
                    print(companyName)
                    print(askPrice)
                    print(percentageChange)

                    returnInfo.name = companyName
                    returnInfo.askPrice = askPrice
                    returnInfo.percentageChange = percentageChange

                } catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return returnInfo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a completion handler to wait for the `async` call `dataTaskWithRequest` to complete. Modify your code like:

```
func getInfo (stock: String, completion: (cName: String, price: String, percentChange: String) -> ()) -> stockData{

//your code
let companyName: String = quote["Name"] as! String
                let askPrice: String = quote["Ask"] as! String
                let percentageChange: String = quote["ChangeinPercent"] as! String


                // Places JSON data into return struct
                print(companyName)
                print(askPrice)
                print(percentageChange)
             completion(cName: companyName, price: askPrice, percentChange: percentageChange)

}
//your code
```

And then whenever you want to call this, essentially after a button press or if you prefer in `viewDidLoad` do this:

```
getInfo("your string") {(name, price, change) in
///use the three values how you want.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that was super helpful! As I'm just learning about swift I have one more quick question for you if you don't mind. How would I go about using it with UILabel whenever I try to insert the code where your comment reads ///use the three values how you want; Using self.uilablename.text = name it does not seem to be passed through. What am I doing wrong? Again I can't be more grateful for your help!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Here is what is showing in the console, after waiting 5 minutes it seems like it does sometimes update the label, but it is not doing it constantly. Would you have any thoughts on why this would happen:  "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release."

Comment: Do it on the main thread. After `(name...) in` add this `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.uilablename.text = name })`.

Comment: Might be an ignorant question (sorry I'm still learning), how would I go about changing this to run on the main thread instead of a background one?

Comment: This is the main thread.

Comment: Your awesome, thank you so much! I'll have to do some more reading into async, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Anytime. Feel free to ask when you get stuck. :)